# How to force the browser to render the page applying a specific media type

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine I have a html page with a label on it and I want this label to be green on the screen but red when you print it.

My best solution would be specify the media type on the CSS:

```
@media print {
  #lable {color: red}
}
@media screen {
  #lable {color: green}
}
```

But now imagine I have a tool that takes any URL and converts its contents to a PDF document (I own both the tool and the URL target page). I would like to generate the PDF with the printable layout instead of the version I see on the screen.

So I would set a query string parameter to tell my page to render "as a printable document". Something like: www.myPage.com?viewAsPrint=true

Now I need a way to, using javascript, tell the browser to render the page applying the styles for media print (even though I will be seeing it on the screen).

**Question:** Is that possible?

---

Alternatively I can split my CSS rules between 2 different files (print.css and screen.css) and then, using javascript load the print.css only when viewAsPrint is present in query string. But I'm trying to avoid this solution as it will be easy to get conflicts between the rules in different files.

Thanks

Comment: In fact this is the best solution, if css and html does it for you why use js?

Comment: Why not just hit Ctrl + P and choose "Save as PDF"?

Comment: Are you sure the PDF scraper will actually evaluate JavaScript? - The other option is to detect viewAsPrint server side and then return whatever you want.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks. That's an important observation. And yes, EvoPdf supports javascript.

Comment: I found this in trying to NOT keep hitting the print preview. I wanted to be able to open dev tools in Chrome and adjust layout CSS. Just from this post I realized I just had to change 'print' to 'screen' to see the defined printable area, temporarily, and then change back when satisfied with layout.